# Unix shell - syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: unix, ksh

Below is my code.

```
#!/bin/ksh
curdate=$(date '+%d%h,%Y')
while read line;
do
  echo "$line" > new10.txt
  str0=$(cut -f 2 new10.txt)
  str01=$(cut -f 1 -d ',' new10.txt)
  str1=$(cut -f 2 -d ',' new10.txt)
  str2=$(cut -c 3 $str1)
  if [ $str2=':' ];
  then
    str2=',2016'
    finalstr=$str01$str2
    if [ '01jan2017' -le $finalstr -le $curdate ];
    then
      finalstr1=$str01',2017'
    else
      finalstr1=$str01',2016'
      echo $finalstr1 > datefinal.txt
    fi
done < /export/home/islams/PISAS/userwiseutil/date.txt
```

I am getting following errors:
date1.sh: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
date1.sh: line 22:`done < /export/home/islams/PISAS/userwiseutil/date.txt'

Comment: You haven't closed one of your `if` statements. I see two `if` and only one `fi`. Also, you should use indentation to make things easier to read.

Comment: Look, I've added indentation and the problem becomes apparent. Please indent before posting to stackoverflow, it's more pleasant to read your post and it will solve this kind of error

Comment: Thanks alot and sorry for my silly mistake.Could you please let me know if the if statement for comparing date within a range is correct ?

Comment: you can not compare 3 things in one if statement. Consider using format yyyymmdd, that will make comparing dates easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ksh
curdate=$(date '+%d%h,%Y')
while read line;
do
  echo "$line" > new10.txt
  str0=$(cut -f 2 new10.txt)
  str01=$(cut -f 1 -d ',' new10.txt)
  str1=$(cut -f 2 -d ',' new10.txt)
  str2=$(cut -c 3 $str1)
  if [ $str2=':' ];
  then
    str2=',2016'
    finalstr=$str01$str2
    if [ '01jan2017' -le $finalstr -le $curdate ];
    then
      finalstr1=$str01',2017'
    else
      finalstr1=$str01',2016'
      echo $finalstr1 > datefinal.txt
    fi
  fi #You missed this
done < /export/home/islams/PISAS/userwiseutil/date.txt
```

You missed one fi